# Find the formal bayes rule

Tags: bayesian, decision-theory

Consider a decision rule as an interval, $\delta(x) = [a_1,a_2], \ a_1 \leq a_2, \ a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and the loss function

$$L(y,a) = L(y,[a_1,a_2]) = (a_2-a_1) + c(1-1_{y \in [a_1,a_2]}).$$

Object is to find the formal Bayes rule, where $p_{Y|X} $ is an unimodal distribution. The posterior risk is

$$r(\delta |x) = \mathbb{E}[L(y,\delta(x)) |X=x] = \int L(y,\delta(x))p_{Y|X}dy \\
=\int_{\mathcal{Y}} \big((a_2-a_1) + c(1-1_{y \in [a_1,a_2]})\big)p_{Y|X}dy \\ 
= (a_2-a_1) + c(1- \int_{a_1}^{a_2}p_{Y|X}dy) \\
= (a_2-a_1) + c\big(1- (F_{Y|X}(a_2)-F_{Y|X}(a_1))\big)$$

So we get penalized for chosing a big interval, but also penalized for missing the outcome. If $\delta = \lim_{z \to \infty} (-z,z),$ then $r \to \infty$. If $\delta = \emptyset,$ then $r = c$.

The formal Bayes rule can be stated as:

$$ \min_{a_1,a_2} (a_2-a_1) + c\big(1- (F_{Y|X}(a_2)-F_{Y|X}(a_1))\big).$$

Can we proceed even further? I've not yet used the fact that the distribution $p_{Y|X} $ is unimodal.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you, corrected it!

Comment: We studied a range of similar questions in [Casella et al (1994).](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-2618-5_18)